# How to switch off my laptop speaker when headphones is plugged

Tags: audio, alsa

I've Kubutu 15.04 then KDE Plasma 5 and my laptop speaker doesn't switch off when headphones is plugged. Here my alsamixer snaptshot:

[image]

My laptop is a ASUS N550L
My sound card I found with lspci:

```
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 09)
```

And aplay  result :

```
aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC668 Analog [ALC668 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC668 Digital [ALC668 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Thanks for your help